# How to install Maximus V Gene motherboard drivers on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2012

When I insert the disc to install my Maximus V Gene motherboard drivers on Windows Server 2012 I get the following error:

```
Support CD Setup Program

ASUS CD does not support this operating system(WNT_6.21_64.)
```

Anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: You are attempting to install Windows 8 x64 drivers correct?  You won't be able to use the cd in a case like this.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is from the outdated ASUS driver aggregator software. This is exactly why it is not recommended to install the drivers from the CD. Just download the latest drivers (separate for all components) from their manufacturer websites.

- [intel.com](http://intel.com) (chipset, NIC, SATA, ME)
- [realtek.com.tw](http://realtek.com.tw) (audio)
- [asmedia.com.tw](http://asmedia.com.tw) (USB3)

The only technology I am not 100% sure is supported under Server 2012 is Lucid Virtu. You could try installing Windows 7 drivers from

- [lucidlogix.com](http://lucidlogix.com)

Answer (score 0):

That's a desktop "gaming" motherboard, and most likely doesn't have (Windows 2012) Server drivers available for it, since they usually don't support server OS's on desktop boards.

If Asus doesn't offer them for download (which they don't seem to on support.asus.com), you'll have to dig them up manually from component manufacturers (like Intel, etc.), and/or force installs of the Asus-supplied Windows 8 drivers one at a time (if it lets you), and/or just NOT use certain devices you can't get drivers for.

Comment: There is nothing special about this "gaming" motherboard (besides the marketing hype). It has pretty much all standard components supported by Windows 8/2012 Server.

Comment: @AlexP. I agree.  It's (just) a desktop board, and Asus doesn't support "server" drivers for desktop boards, and often purposefully disallows the driver and utility packages from installing on an unsupported OS, even if the hardware and driver are actually compatible.

Comment: That's why I suggested they check with the individual component manufacturers (which is also what you suggested in your answer), and/or try and force them in from the CD (or Asus' download site) one at a time, instead of relying on the utility that the CD seems to be auto-starting (which checks the OS and quits because it's not a supported OS). It could also be that the CD ONLY contains 32-bit drivers, and therefore the 64-bit OS is unsupported by the disk.